# Use Scrollview on Container

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, scrollrect

I was playing around with Unity's UI stuff and what I'm trying to implement right now is a list of images that can be scrolled through. However, the Scrollrect only provides scrolling a single image rather than a container.
Have u got any ideas to still make use of the Scrollrect rather than coding a custom class for scroling containers? My first and very inelegant thought was to create a GameObject with a large image that is dynamically resized based on the most far away images it contains....
Ty for your help in advance!

Comment: Unity tag in SO isn't intended for Unity3d game engine. Please use unity3d tag.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to make use of this component:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.VerticalLayoutGroup.html

Comment: I think, just grid layout group is what I was looking for, thanks